# my dog trithlon program gives errors

Tags: java, error-handling, static

```
public class DogTriathlonParticipant {
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
static {



}
public static void main(String[] args) {



{
    {
    private static int NUM_EVENTS;
    private static int totalCumulativeScore = 0;

    private final string name;
    private final int obedienceScore;
    private final int conformationScore;
    private final int agilityScore;
    private final int total;
    private final double avg;
    private String name;





    public DogTriathlonParticipant (String name, int numEvents, int score1,
            int score2, int score3)
    {
        {

            {
                {

        this.name = name;
        NUM_EVENTS = numEvents;
        obedienceScore = score1;
        conformationScore = score2;
        agilityScore = score3;

        total = obedienceScore + conformationScore + agilityScore;
        avg = (double) total / NUM_EVENTS;
        totalCumulativeScore = totalCumulativeScore + total; 

        {
            {
                {

                }
            }
        }
        {

        public void display()


        {
            System.out.println(name + " participated in " + NUM_EVENTS + " Events and has an average score of " + avg);
            System.out.println( " " + name + " has total score of " + total + " bringing the total cumlative score to " + totalCumulativeScore);

        } 

        public class TestDogs
        {

        }
        public static void main(String[] args)
            {

                {    
            {
        DogTriathlonParticipant dog1 = 
                new DogTriathlonParticipant("Bowser" , 2, 85, 89,0);
        dog1.display();
        {

        }
        DogTriathlonParticipant dog2 = 
                new DogTriathlonParticipant("Rush", 3, 78, 72, 80);
        dog2.display();
        {

        }
        DogTriathlonParticipant dog3 =
                new DogTriathlonParticipant("Ginger", 3, 90, 86, 72);
        dog3.display();
        }
        }
    }
}
```

it keeps giving errors to my names and string and also the public voids 
maybe I just need a fresh eye to help me figure out the errors and why they say they are illegal 
and fi you could figure it out can you also explain to me why so I can learn why?
I'm using netbeans and rather new to java

Comment: Is this code in one java page? you don't create a new page for your custom class (DogTriathlonParticipant)?

Comment: You can't put methods inside of other methods.

Comment: which method is inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you goal is to create DogTriathlonParticipant instances and "test" the instanciation by displaying the information, you may first separate your logic in different java classes / pages.

You should create new Java class in netbeans for the main, and the DogTriathlonParticipant class. To do so, click on Source Packages > new > Java Class.

Name that class DogTriathlonParticipant as show below :

```
public class DogTriathlonParticipant {

//private static int NUM_EVENTS;
//private static int totalCumulativeScore = 0; //this logic is not part of DogTriathlonParticipant.

// you should not put final if you plan to edit the variable.
private String name;
private int obedienceScore;
private int conformationScore;
private int agilityScore;
private int total;
private double avg;
private String name;

public DogTriathlonParticipant (String name, int numEvents, int score1, int score2, int score3) {
    this.name = name;
    // NUM_EVENTS = numEvents; this logic don't belong here
    obedienceScore = score1;
    conformationScore = score2;
    agilityScore = score3;

    total = obedienceScore + conformationScore + agilityScore;
    avg = (double) total / numEvents; // edited here, I think you are trying to get the average of to total by numEvents, in this case, the score1 shoulb be the sum of the events "numEvents".
    //totalCumulativeScore = totalCumulativeScore + total; 
}

public void display()
    {
        System.out.println(name + " participated in " + numEvents+ " Events and has an average score of " + avg);
        System.out.println( " " + name + " has total score of " + total + " bringing the total cumlative score to " + total);
    } 
 }
```

Then you should have your "test" class like this :

```
public class TestDogs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DogTriathlonParticipant dog1 = new DogTriathlonParticipant("Bowser" , 2, 85, 89,0);
        DogTriathlonParticipant dog2 = new DogTriathlonParticipant("Rush", 3, 78, 72, 80);
        DogTriathlonParticipant dog3 = new DogTriathlonParticipant("Ginger", 3, 90, 86, 72);

        dog1.display();
        dog2.display();
        dog3.display();
    }
}
```

With that, you should have a good base to start and add your logic and correct the one in place.